# gremlin in python NameError not recognising functions

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am running Gremlin-Pyton in a Jupyter notebook and for some reason the following does not work:

```
g.V().group().by().by(bothE().count())
```

I keep getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'bothE' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the [typical imports listed in the documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-python):

```
>>> from gremlin_python import statics
>>> from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
>>> from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
>>> from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
>>> from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
```

then `bothE` is available as `__.bothE`.

The methods in the `__` namespace can be added to your notebook globals with:

```
>>> statics.load_statics(globals())
```

so you can access `bothE` directly without a prefix.

Quoting from the documentation:

> Moreover, by importing the statics of Gremlin-Python, the class prefixes can be omitted.
>
> ```
> >>> statics.load_statics(globals())
> ```

and

> Finally, statics includes all the -methods and thus, anonymous traversals like `.out()` can be expressed as below. That is, without the `__.`-prefix.
>
> ```
> >>> g.V().repeat(out()).times(2).name.fold().toList()
> [[ripple, lop]]
> ```

---

*Caveat*: I am not a Gremlin-Python user nor is it practical for me to install Gremlin to verify the above completely. I based this on reading the documentation and a scan of the project source code.

Comment: thank you where do i run the "statics.load_statics(globals())", when i run it in my jupyter notebook it does not work nor in my gremlin console

Comment: @Maths12: 'does not work' is not really something I can work with. What happens instead? It's Python code, run it in your notebook like you ran the `from gremlin_python import ...` statements, without the `>>>` prefix.

Comment: NameError: name 'statics' is not defined <-- this is the error. and i have imported all the imports listed in documentation.

Comment: The name error suggests you are missing `from gremlin_python import statics`. The `statics.load_statics(globals())` line can only run *after* you imported `statics`.

Comment: thanks, i did do that import for some reason it wasn;t being recognised. I have imported a different way and it works now

Comment: One word of caution - doing the static import can cause some name collisions that are not always obvious and take time debugging. I say this from painful experience :-) I personally prefer the long hand form just to be on the safe side.